# Dwarf hunter Cloak of Shadows and Vanish?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Can a dwarf hunter perform the following?

1. The hunter has *Glyph of Play Dead* and *Glyph of Camouflage*.
2. The hunter enters combat with another player.
3. The hunter activates a macro that casts *Stoneform*, *Feign Death* and *Camouflage*, in that order.
4. The hunter and his pet are both stealthed and untargetable for 1 minute.

The idea is that *Stoneform* acts like *Cloak of Shadows*. Then *Feign Death* removes both the hunter and his pet from combat, so that *Camouflage* is up for its entire duration instead of the 6 second limit when it is cast in combat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perform the action without fail.  However, I do so believe this to be ineffective as far as an Arena tactic would go, even a 1vX battle would seem unlikely to prevail due to mass AOE used when rogues Shadow Step.  Having someone around to mitigate damage would prove more useful.  I would also like to point out the Feign Death only helps your pet not you.

Comment: During 1V1 open-pvp, that could work. However, i do agree with Virusboy that it will most likely fail in party PvP, wether open or battlegrounds, because of AoE attacks. Your enemy, in 1v1, will probably instantly switch to AoE in an attempt to uncloack you, so you should move out as fast as possible. (I'm not sure, but if disengage does not break cloaking, use it and get away as fast as possible.)

Comment: Yea I meant to put in a 1v1 Open PvP it would only be effective in.